# security interceptor not excluding resource folder in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, interceptor

I am trying to exclude the resource folder to call interceptor but still it is calling the interceptors pre handle method

```
registry.addInterceptor(securityInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**")
  .excludePathPatterns(/resources/**);
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I would suggest you to be more specific in what you need, and also properly format whatever code you want to bring to other people's attention. See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you please show me securityInterceptor..